# Convert NSString to CLLocationCoordinate2DMake using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring

How can I convert NSString to CLLocationCoordinate2DMake. I want to make a marker on map. Here is what I have done but I am getting "NSString is not convertable to CLLocationDegrees" error.

```
for openComplain in openComplains {

                                var lat = openComplain["lat"] as NSString
                                var long = openComplain["lng"] as NSString
                                NSLog("Lat is %@",lat)
                                NSLog("long is %@",long)




                                var complainLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)

                                var marker : GMSMarker = GMSMarker(position: complainLoc)
                                marker.title = "Complain 1"
                                marker.map = self.mapView
                            }
```

I have tried

```
var lat = (openComplain["lat"] as NSString).doubleValue
var long = (openComplain["lng"] as NSString).doubleValue
```

But in that case I am getting null value. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to unwrap the dictionary optional value before converting it to Double:

```
var lat  = (openComplain["lat"]! as NSString).doubleValue
var long = (openComplain["lng"]! as NSString).doubleValue
```